# python pandas: multiple based on user input

Tags: python, pandas

Newbie here....im creating a dataframe that allows use input to filter the data multiple times. However currently what I'm doing now only allows the user to filter data once. What are the possible ways to apply multiple filtering in a neat and short way?should I assign the filtered data frame to the variable, and use the variable to filter again if the user wishes to continue filtering?  for example:"filter 1 then filter 2"

````
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Name","Unit Price","Quantity","Price","Expiry Date","Expired?"]) 
def call(var,input_type):
    x=int(input("Enter '0' to search for item/s with more than the inputted value\nEnter '1' to search for item/s with less than the inputted value'\nEnter '2' to search for item/s with the inputted value\nEnter your choice:"))
    p=(input_type(input("Enter the value: ")))
    dict = {0: df.loc[df[var] > p], 1: df.loc[df[var] < p], 2:df.loc[df[var] == p]}
    print(dict[x])
    
def filter():
    cont=True
    while cont==True:
        n=int(input("Filtering based on:\n1)Name\n2)Unit price\n3)Price\n4)Quantity\n5)Expired date\nEnter your choice:"))
        if n==1:
            method=int(input("Enter '0' to search for item/s by inputting name\nEnter '1' to search for item/s that contain the inputted words\nEnter '2' to search for item/s that start with the inputted word\nEnter '3' to search for item/s that end with the inputted words"))
            if method==0:
                
                word=input("Enter the item's name: ")
                print(df.loc[df["Name"]==word])
            elif method== 1:
                word=input("Enter the word/s the item contain")
                print(df.loc[df["Name"].str.contains(word,flags=re.IGNORECASE)])
            elif method ==2:
                word=input("Enter the word/s the item start with")
                print(df.loc[df["Name"].str.startswith(word)])
            elif method ==3:
                word=input("Enter the word/s the item end with")
                print(df.loc[df["Name"].str.endswith(word)])
        elif n==2:
            
            call("Unit Price",int)
        elif n==3:
            call("Price",float)
        elif n==4:
            call("Quantity",int)
        elif n==5:
            x=int(input("Enter '0' to search for item/s with an expiry date exceeding the inputted date\nEnter '1' to search for item/s with an expired date not yet exceeding the inputted expiry date: "))
            print("Enter a date: ")
            year = int(input('Enter a year'))                          
            month = int(input('Enter a month'))    
            day = int(input('Enter a day'))
            expired_date = datetime.date(year, month, day)
            dict = {0: df.loc[df["Expiry Date"] > expired_date], 1: df.loc[df["Expiry Date"] < expired_date]}
            print(dict[x])
        
        y=input("Continue filtering?\nY/N\nEnter your choice: ")
        if y=="Y":
            f()
        elif y=="N":
            cont=False
                ```
````

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to have multiple filters like "filter1 & filter2", "filter1 | filter2" or "filter1 then filter2", etc.

Comment: "filter1 then filter2",